# Excel TextToColumns method in VBA to ignore formulas

Tags: excel, vba, methods, excel-formula

First, let me say that I hope that it is proper SO etiquette to be asking this in the same post as my original. It's all in the same vein, but I'm not sure this is proper. So, please, if I'm not right, correct me so I can fix it.

I created a macro to perform a TextToColumns a while back. I edited and cleaned up the macro. It was working just fine until I started propagating data into those fields using formulas instead of manually copying data into them, which was what I used to do.

Now, I've expanded on my worksheet's module code and realized that the method I wrote months ago interferes with formulas that now copy the values into the fields that I originally was performing the TextToColumns.

In short, is there a way to tell .TextToColumns to take the *values* of the range in which it's working and ignore the formula?

```
 Sheet4.Range(categorySrcColumn & srcCategoryColLastRow)
       .TextToColumns _
            Destination:=Range(categoryDestColumn), _
            Other:=True, _
            OtherChar:="/", _
            FieldInfo:=Array(1,1), _
            TrailingMinusNumbers:=true
```

I checked the documentation for TextToColumns searching for xlValues but couldn't find anything like that.

---------- addendum -----------

Rachel. I appreciate your input. Perhaps you could assist a little bit more. I've plugged in your suggestion, but it simply is doing nothing. I've taken a few libterties here in hopes to combine what you've given with what I need. Disclaimer: I am by no means a VBA developer. What I know is what I've learned from google. I live in the Unix/Linux world so this is a very different bird to what I'm used to.

Here's what I have so far...

```
Public Function sbTextToColumn(srcRange As String, dstRange As String)
    Dim vData As Variant

    vData = Split(ActiveSheet.Range(srcRange).Value, "/")

    ' I need to massage the data in the srcRange a bit before I can separate it out. 
    ' This is a partial sanity check on the data as well.
    Range(srcRange).Replace What:="I/R", Replacement:="IR", Lookat:=xlPart, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False _
                    ReplaceFormat:=False

    Range(srcRange).Replace What:="N/A", Replacement:="NA", Lookat:=xlPart, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False _
                    ReplaceFormat:=False

    Range(srcRange).Replace What:=" ", Replacement:="", Lookat:=xlPart, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False _
                    ReplaceFormat:=False

    ActiveSheet.Range(dstRange).Resize(ColumnSize:=UBound(vData) + 1) = vData
    sbTextToColumn = ""
End Function
```

I cannot post an example of the spreadsheet, unfortunately. It's on a closed, secure network.

Now, when I plug this in in the worksheet via: `=sbTextToColumn(C836, E836)`, nothing happens.

This is my first attempt at ever creating and using a UDF. Here's how I'm calling the function. I have a worksheet with the first three columns A-C grabbing data from another spreadsheet. Those columns are of course formulas. Column D is not used, but I'm placing the call to the UDF in here, hoping that that will work. Columns E-I are reserved for the T2C data and column J is used by pulling the same data as column B (yes, redundant, I know). My goal is that I'd like to get rid of column J (it's used for a vlookup in another worksheet and I may not be able to remove it but I'd like to). Ideally, I'd like to pull the source data from the other spreadsheet, sanity check it, split it out, and simply place the sorted data in the n columns necessary.

So, am I on the right track? I'm still working on this. If I make any progress, I'll post the progress. TIA!

Comment: Ok. So, I'm going to go out on a limb here and say that there's no way for me to do this. I've decided to try and attack this from a different angle. The flow of this little project of mine loosely follows this: source spreadsheet -> stats spreadsheet -> stats charts. The texttocolumns that I currently perform occurs in the stats spreadsheet portion, which values now come from formulas in that spreadsheet. Now, I'm going to run the texttocolumns on the source data instead of the destination worksheet. Let's see how I fair. I will probably have more questions stem from this methodology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions, including UDFs, can only return a value to their caller. They *cannot* modify other cells.

Here is Rachel's method wrapped as a UDF:

```
Function sbTextToColumn(rng As Range) As Variant
    Dim vData As Variant

    vData = Split(rng.Value2, "/")
    ReDim Preserve vData(0 To Application.Caller.Columns.Count - 1)
    sbTextToColumn = vData
End Function
```

You  enter it as a array function.  In your example, say for `row 2`

- Select range `E2:I1`
- Type `=sbTextToColumn(C2)`
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>
- Copy the 5 cell range down for as many rows as needed

Functions not being able to modify other cells means you cannot do the sanitising in the UDF.

From your sample code you want to

- Replace I/R with IR, and N/A with NA
- Remove spaces
- Do this after the data is split out into columns `E:I`  (so I/R will already be split into two cells)
- Replace the original Column C *formulas* with sanitised data as *values*

Is this right?

If so, you would be best to not used a UDF at all, but rather use a `Sub` (called from a quick key, or added to a menu)

Somthing like:

```
Sub sbTextToColumn()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim srcRng As Range
    Dim rw As Range
    Dim vData As Variant
    Dim srcData As Variant
    Dim dstData As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim maxCol As Long

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set srcRng = Range(ws.Columns(3).Cells(1, 1), _
        ws.Columns(3).Cells(ws.Columns(3).Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

    srcData = srcRng
    ReDim dstData(LBound(srcData, 1) To UBound(srcData, 1), 1 To 5)

    For i = LBound(srcData, 1) To UBound(srcData, 1)
        If srcData(i, 1) <> "" Then
            ' Split data
            vData = Split(srcData(i, 1), "/")
            maxCol = UBound(vData, 1)
            If maxCol > 5 Then maxCol = 5
            For j = 1 To maxCol + 1
                dstData(i, j) = vData(j - 1)
            Next

            ' Sanitise data
            srcData(i, 1) = Replace(srcData(i, 1), "I/R", "IR", Compare:=vbTextCompare)
            srcData(i, 1) = Replace(srcData(i, 1), "N/A", "NA", Compare:=vbTextCompare)
            srcData(i, 1) = Replace(srcData(i, 1), " ", "", Compare:=vbTextCompare)
        End If
    Next

    ' Put results back in sheet
    srcRng = srcData
    srcRng.Offset(0, 2).Resize(, 5) = dstData
End Sub
```

If you actually want to sanitise before the split, simply swap the order of the  Split data and Sanitise Data code blocks.

Comment: We're getting closer. Thank you for your reply. So, my code example was poorly written by your synopsis of what I was attempting to do based on my code. Actually, it needs to be in the sequence: fix N/A, I/R, and Spaces first, then split out the field delimited by '/' placing the result in individual n cells of the same row. As for column C, what would be ideal is that I can place the formula in that cell that triggers the Sub. The value of the first element of the array in the result from the sub would be in C.value2 but the formula would remain in tact. I really appreciate your help!!

Comment: Happy to help, Jim.  There are some finer points we need to get sorted before progressing:  1. is `N/A` & `I/R` always upper case, or should `n/a` etc also be replaced 2. does something like `aN/Another` count as `N/A` 3. could the sanitising part be built in to the formula in column `C`, perhaps by converting it to a UDF 4. is the maximum number of `/` seperated components limited to 5 or should the solution handle any number, or some other larger maximum number

Comment: (continued)  5. having Excel respond to entry of a formula in a cell is possible with a `Change` event on the sheet.  Basically, the event is triggered whenever anything on the sheet changes, and identifies the ranges that changed. Your logic then determines if the change meets some criteria and then executes some action.  Does this sound like a viable solution?

Comment: Ok. 1. They should probably be case-insensitive.  2. No. It will always be NA, IR, or some other small categorical term that doesn't even come close to a word. 3. I don't see that that would be a problem. I would prefer for this to be as automatic as possible without the need for users to trigger the event manually. 4. There is currently a limit of five and that will probably never get hit, but that limit should probably be removed just in case.

Again, I truly appreciate your help. This has been a real pain! :)

Comment: I see two ways forward: 1. use formulas. To sanitise your data either wrap your existing formual in `=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(YourFormula,"N/A","NA"),"I/R","IR")," ","")` or convert it to a UDF.  Use an array version of the UDFs as above to split the data.  Apply it to a suitable range to allow for the practical max number of results.  Or 2. go the Event route.  This will get complicated, and while once working it will be easy for the user, it will be a PITA to maintain.  Personally I would probably go with option 1 and convert your existing formula to a UDF with sanitising built in

Comment: Let's go with  option 1 then. I didn't know I could do that. The formula would be, then, what Rachel suggested? I think I can do that and I have no problem suppressing the output to 5 columns. chances of the data getting larger than that is really really rare! At least I know that this issue wasn't a trivial one to solve.

Comment: Use the version as described at the top of my answer.  I've made a small edit to avoid returning N/A'a if there is less then 5 values in the result

Comment: So let me see if I understand what's going on. The formula (I've called sbTextToColumns) is called first in precedence. It pulls the data from my source spreadsheet, splits the strings by "/" into an array, and returns the array to the substitutes(). The substitutes() alter the strings in each field and only the number of elements in vData fill in the number of column fields in the row. Correct? My formula looks like this: {=substitute(substitute(substitute(sbTextToColumn('[SS.xlsm]WS'!$H$840),"N/A","NA"),"I/R","IR")," ","")} and it is in 5 column fields.

Comment: Not quite what I had in mind.  I had assumed you want the immediate 
results of the other sheets in columns C.  So C would contain `=substitute(substitute(substitute('[SS.xlsm]WS'!$H$840),"N/A","N‌​A"),"I/R","IR")," ","")' `E:I` would contain `{=sbTextToColumn(C2)}`  You could do it in one step, but the substitutes need to be done before the split, so in this case modify `sbTextToColumn` to include the substitutes.  Something like `vData = Split(replace(replace(replace(rng.Value2,"N/A","NA"),"I/A","IA")," ",""), "/")` and call is as `{=sbTextToColumn('[SS.xlsm]WS'!$H$840)}`

Answer (score 3):

This approach might work for you as it utilizes the Value property and is unaffected by formulas. It uses the Split function to split the data into a one-dimensional array. That array is then pasted into the cells to the right:

```
Sub sbTextToColumn()
    Dim vData As Variant
    vData = Split(Sheet4.Range("A1").Value, "/")
    Sheet4.Range("B1").Resize(ColumnSize:=UBound(vData) + 1) = vData
End Sub
```

Comment: nicely done Rachel. For larger data sets it might be worth using `value2` rather than `value`

Comment: @rachel please see addendum in OP. Thanks! I really appreciate your assistance!